# I want to use asterisk as wildcard

Tags: .net, vb.net

Following code is okey.

```
    If Label1.Text = "WELCOME HOME" Then
        MsgBox("Hello")
    End If
```

Following code is not okey. (I want to use asterisk as wildcard)

```
    If Label1.Text = "*WELCOME HOME*" Then
        MsgBox("Hello")
    End If
```

Any idea?

Comment: The equality operator compares for ... equality. It is *not* a regular expression or a search function. Either use `String.Contains` without wildcards or use a regular expresssion with the `Regex` class

Comment: Since *label* text is under the control of your program, why does your program need to have logic based on the current label text? If this is some kind of "If I'm in X state, do Y" then I'd strongly suggest that you explicitly store your states rather than trying to determine your state based on how you've changed the UI state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing strings doesn't work that way, you should use the `Contains()` function:

```
 If Label1.Text.Contains("WELCOME HOME") Then
        MsgBox("Hello")
 End If
```

The equality check should be done with the `Equals()` method. Comparison with `=` actually works in VB.Net, but I think it is less clear and might be mistaken for an assignment.

```
If Label1.Text.Equals("WELCOME HOME") Then
            MsgBox("Hello")
End If
```

Comment: @Kramer Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you. How about if `Label1.Text=WELCOME MY HOME` and I am looking for `WELCOME HOME` ?

Comment: @Kramer for WELCOME MY HOME you can use this [RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/hI4mU2/1) : `^WELCOME.*HOME$`. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) how to use it in VB.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved.